# Saving into CoreData Context on background thread

Tags: ios, objective-c, multithreading, core-data

I am struggling with this for some time now and Apple's documentation and SO did not help so far. I was using ManagedObjectContext on a UIManagedDocument and the code below worked fine. I then decided to use Apple's template for CoreData in AppDelegate, so model, persistent store coordinator and context is created in AppDelegate. Fetching with AppDelegate's context is no problem, but background saving is an issue. I should have local context on the thread I am saving and as per Apple to have same persistance store coordinator. But the code below does not actually save the data. Can someone here please advise? Thank you.

```
- (void)fetchAndPersist
{
    dispatch_queue_t ffetchQ = dispatch_queue_create("ForFetch", NULL);
    dispatch_async(ffetchQ, ^{

        NSManagedObjectContext *secureManagedObjectContext;
        NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *coordinator = [appDelegate persistentStoreCoordinator];
        if (coordinator != nil) {
            secureManagedObjectContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] init];
            [secureManagedObjectContext setPersistentStoreCoordinator:coordinator];
        }

        // find missing date
        DataManager *dataManager = [[DataManager alloc] init];
        NSDate *missingDate = [dataManager findMissingDateFromDate:selectedDate inContext:secureManagedObjectContext];

        if (missingDate) {
            // fetch and parse data
            DataFetcher *dataFetcher = [[dataFetcher alloc] init];
            NSDictionary *fetchResponse = [dataFetcher parseDataForDate:missingDate];

            // persist it in a block and wait for it
            [secureManagedObjectContext performBlock:^{
                DataStore *dataStore = [[DataStore alloc] init];
                BOOL parsingError = [dataStore persistData:fetchResponse inContext:secureManagedObjectContext];

                if (parsingError) {
                    // handle error
                } else {
                    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                        // perform on main
                        [self fetchAndPersist];
                    });
                }
            }];
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Why save in another thread ? Is it really necessary for what you are doing in this instance ?

Comment: If you mean by 'saving in another thread' the performBlock operation, then it's not. All I need is the simpliest fetch and persist operation the goes outside main thread.

Comment: To clarify, currently the code will crash with report 'Can only use -performBlock: on an NSManagedObjectContext that was created with a queue.' If I comment out the performBlock line, the code runs in infinite loop, so the main thread does not see the data that has been saved.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Try to use parent / child contexts:

http://www.cocoanetics.com/2012/07/multi-context-coredata/

In the link above you can find a code sample.

Answer (score 3):

Your crash occurs because your `NSManagedObjectContext` is using the older, [obsolete thread confinement model for Core Data concurrency](http://quellish.tumblr.com/post/97430076027/a-real-guide-to-core-data-concurrency):

`secureManagedObjectContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] init];`

`init` is just a wrapper around `initWithConcurrencyType:` with the argument `NSConfinementConcurrencyType`. This creates the context using the thread confinement model, which cannot use `performBlock:` or `performBlockAndWait:`. Only contexts using the newer (not obsolete!) queue confinement model can use these methods, and have to use these methods for any access to the context or objects belonging to it. To create a context using queue confinement and a private queue:

`secureManagedObjectContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType];`

If your code was migrated to using a private queue context you could also remove your serial dispatch queue, as the private queue context provides equivalent functionality.

Comment: What do you mean "and have to use these methods for any access to the context or objects belonging to it".  I'm using the new Concurrency types, and perfomBlock and performBlockAndWait are not at all required to use the context to save/fetch data.  Maybe I misunderstand?

Comment: Yes, you must use those methods to get correct behavior. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/DataManagement/RN-CoreData/