# iOS: Chat application with CoreData

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, chat, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I am developing a chat application for iOS. The app will allow users to create chat room and chat with members in the chat room (like IRC chat room).

The flow of the app is;

1. User can join chat rooms
2. Messages will be stored in coradata backed SQLite
   DB
3. There are no reference for local messages and the messages in the server (all the
   messages which are related to a particular user are only stored in his local DB)
4. I am using NSFetchResultController to update and refresh the chat
   table. When a chat is received it will be stored to DB and the table view will load the new chat.
5. All the core data operations are done in main thread
6. The `batchsize` for fetch request is 20 and `performfetch` method is
   called in `viewDidLoad`

**Problems**

1. When a chat is received the UI hangs for a while (1 -
   2 sec in iPhone 4) . (If I pause the execution it shows that there
   is something happening in [tableview endUpdate] in fetch controller
   delegate)
2. To go to the latest chat in a chat view currently the user has to
   load all the chats from DB

**Questions**

1. Are there any better way to handle this requirement? is it ok to use fetchresultcontroller?
2. How can I load the chats in a paginated manner -like what sup or
   viber - using `fetchresultcontroller`.
3. If I use background mode with multiple managed object context would there be any performance improvements?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

1. It's very good even to use the NSFetchedResultsController, it's designed for such operations.
2. The batch size is kind of like pagination. Take a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7955486/paging-results-from-core-data-requests), the first answer shows how to use limits and batch sizes like pagination.
3. Depends on what you mean, updating/saving to core data could very well be handled in a background thread (and I would suggest to do so). Fetching is a different story, remember that [all UI changes have to be be done on the main thread.](http://www.cocoabuilder.com/archive/cocoa/315103-why-is-the-threading-and-ui-updating-designed-to-be-done-only-on-main-thread.html).

It is best to consider data mutation and data fetching as two separate tasks, this way you can optimise both in it's on way. I highly consider reading [this article](http://www.cocoanetics.com/2012/07/multi-context-coredata/) for more information on the matter:

> CoreData guru Marcus Zarra has shown me the following approach which builds on the above Parent/Child method but adds an additional context exclusively for writing to disk. As alluded to earlier a lenghty write operation might block the main thread for a short time causing the UI to freeze. This smart approach uncouples the writing into its own private queue and keeps the UI smooth as button. [image]

Answer (score 3):

You will need to do the CoreData stuff on a background thread.  There are lots of examples out there ([here's one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18812130/saving-into-coredata-context-on-background-thread)) for doing this, but my suggestion is to use [MagicalRecord](https://github.com/magicalpanda/MagicalRecord), it makes CoreData concurrency operations really easy.

Comment: Learning Core Data itself will go a lot further than using a third party framework that wraps Core Data.  Even the creator of MagicalRecord has stated that you are better off learning Core Data **first**.  Creating child contexts and `NSOperation` subclasses is not an advanced subject and is worth learning.

Comment: Can't argue with the master of Core Data :)  Very true.

Answer (score 0):

> All the core data operations are done in main thread

This is your problem. Only object access via `NSFetchResultController` should be on the main thread. Updating `NSManagedObject`s should be done on a background queue with a concurrent child `NSManagedObjectContext`.

Comment: I'm not so sure. How can it take 1 to 2 seconds to insert a new row and then fetch it? This should be fast enough to do on the main thread, I think there's something else going on.

Comment: Core Data, `NSFetchedResultsController` in particular, not only "inserts and fetches" the models. It queries for partial objects, monitors changes, fires faults when model attribute values are needed, handles changes, saves to disk, and so on. If you make updates and saves on the main thread, you are needlessly blocking the supposedly read-only `NSFetchedResultsController`.

Comment: Yeah I know it does all that, but in my experience it happens in microseconds, not seconds. I do use a separate context on a background thread for things that are slow (eg: inserting 3,000 new entries into the database), but I don't need to bother most of the time. Usually a change is plenty fast enough to be done on the main thread.

Comment: Your use case was probably just lucky. Once you deal with complex relationships or multiple `NSFetchResultController`s, (etc.) even just a few hundreds of records will cause noticeable hiccups.

Answer (score 0):

For your question 2.

You create a new array -namely chatArray - and take last 20 chats from your DB, then load the chat table view with chatArray.
show a load more button on Tableview header, and when the user reaches top and hit that button-

remove all objects from chatArray, and add last 20 chat records from your DB then again reload your table. This process go on.

I am not strong in fetchresultcontroller, and will do some studies and let you know for sure.